# ROW_NUMER() error when no data present in DB Sailfish

Tags: sql, db2, partitioning

I am facing a strange error only if there is not data present in the DB(Sailfish/ibm db2 zos).
All columns are integers.

```
SELECT jersey_number,
       team_nm,
       ROW_NUMBER ()
       OVER (
          PARTITION BY Model_Football.member_idn,
                       Model_Football.Arm_Power_Idn,
                       Model_Football.Speed_Idn
          ORDER BY
             Model_Football.member_idn,
             Model_Football.Arm_Power_Idn,
             Model_Football.Speed_Idn)
          AS Dual_threat_id
FROM QB_SCHOOL
WHERE pos = 'QB'
```

```
[IBM][DB2/LINUXPPC64LE] Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".
```

Comment: Are you sure the columns' data types are exactly `INTEGER` (all of them), or do you also have `DECFLOAT` or other?

Comment: Yes they are all integer columns and the dual_threat_id is a BIGINT. So would that affect it?

Comment: I don't clearly see any problem with your query and I use DB2 AIX and LUW all the time. Are you sure the issue is related to this section of the query? Maybe you can comment it out and run the query again.

Comment: According to `[IBM][DB2/LINUXPPC64LE]` it's Linux on Power (Little Endian). @ChristopherFowler: Are you able to reproduce the problem on some smaller example with `CREATE TABLE` and full SELECT statement? If yes, then please, provide such an example.

Comment: In the edited question, the partitioning expression seems invalid, maybe you have omitted something?

Comment: So, I have tried removing just this part and it works fine. It's so strange because I tested it in 2 different pipeline lines and it only fails when speed_idn has any nulls